# Red circle with x button?

Tags: wear-os

When I control Seekbar in Android Wear device, red circle with x button pops up.
There is no exception or force to close dialog. If I push the button, it just terminate the app.
I wonder why red circle with x button pops up and how to avoid that.
thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "red circle with x" is a `DismissOverlayView`, that is,

> A view for implementing *long-press-to-dismiss* in an app.

(as described in the documentation for the [Wearable UI Library](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary)).

The idea is to provide an alternative way to close an app when you specifically prevent *swipe-to-dismiss* (by setting `android:windowSwipeToDismiss="false"`), for example when swiping is an integral part of an app.

A canonical example (as explained in [this Google I/O talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sha_w3_5c2c), around the 23:00 mark) is when displaying a `ViewPager` on the drawable: you may not want the user to accidentally exit the app by swiping right from the first page, but you still need *some* way to exit it.

So they settled on long press as the pattern for doing so.